Why doesn't gravity causing the adiabatic lapse rate violate the laws of thermodynamics?
I'm looking to fully understand how the adiabatic lapse rate works and why it causing warmer air doesn't violate the laws of thermodynamics.
My understanding is as follows: consider a parcel of air high up in the air. This has a certain amount of potential energy. Gravity does work on this air, pulling it downwards, converting potential energy to kinetic energy. This acts to compress the parcel, which causes it to heat up.
However, at the same time, on its way down it is exerting a buyoant force on the parcels of air below it, causing them to rise. These parcels move up to an area of lower pressure, thus expanding and causing them to cool. They are gaining potential energy and losing kinetic energy.
And now... the cycle repeats itself? It seems like gravity is constantly pulling air down and warming it up (potential -> kinetic) while also causing air to buoy up and cool (kinetic -> potential), over and over again. With the net effect of warming the air nearer the surface (e.g. grand canyon base is warmer than the top rim).
Isn't this a perpetual motion machine of the 2nd kind?

all this movement is fueled by an external energy source, the Sun

It's important here to note that still air in a gravity field, in the absence of local heating, tends to a constant temperature. So gravity itself isn't inducing a temperature gradient. It does induce a pressure gradient, however, from the weight of the air.
If we now introduce vertical convection from any source, the lapse rate emerges. Why? Because a parcel of air directed downward through the pressure gradient is spontaneously compressed and thus heats up from the input work, and a parcel of air directed upward spontaneously expands and thus cools down from the outward work.
So the causal factor in this case is the source of the vertical movement and ultimately the source of weather in the atmosphere, which as noted in a comment is predominantly the Sun. (Radiative ground heating, for example, drives natural convection.) Any local decreases in entropy from an emerging temperature gradient are more than paid for by the enormous increase in entropy when (low-entropy) sunlight from a very hot source is absorbed and re-emitted as (high-entropy) thermal radiation at familiar temperatures. A Second Law violation is thus avoided.

It makes sense the sun answers the question. But if gravity itself doesn’t induce the gradient, how come lower elevations are consistently hotter than higher ones? All are essentially equally “seeded” by heating from the Sun

I've edited my answer to clarify this point.
